# Liquibase Rollback Strategy for CI/CD

Tags: tags, continuous-integration, liquibase, cd

in Continuous Deployment you can easily go back to a previous version of your application. This means the database needs to be brought back to a previous state too.

My question is: How do I select the appropriate tag to roll back to? It does not seem to be possible to list all available tags. How does your company links the application version to a liquibase tag? Do you tag after each integration build even if there are no database changes?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you can rollback to time/date if that can help you

Comment: @bilak Unfortunatelly this requires the date a certain database change was made. We would have to save that information somewhere on the buildserver. I was thinking about parsing the db-changes.xml with a script to return a list of tags as next move

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to link the application version to a Liquibase tag. One way is to use a build tool, such as Maven or Gradle. You can configure your build tool to generate a Liquibase tag for each build. Another way to link the application version to a Liquibase tag is to use a continuous integration (CI) server, such as Jenkins or Travis CI. You can configure your CI server to generate a Liquibase tag for each build.